# How to handle i18n in Go?

Tags: internationalization, go

I searched on web but I didn't find anything related to i18n and Go.

I wish to use Go for develop web sites. What is the best way to handle internationalization?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[go-i18n](http://nicksnyder.github.io/go-i18n/) has some nice features:

- Implements [CLDR plural rules](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules).
- Uses [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for strings with variables.
- Translation files are simple JSON.

Answer (score 10):

> [Packages roadmap](http://golang.org/doc/devel/roadmap.html)
>
> ```
> Comprehensive support for international text.
> Support for international dates, times, etc.
> Support for multilingual messages.
> ```

As you can see from the [Go Roadmap](http://golang.org/doc/devel/roadmap.html), Go doesn't provide full i18n support yet.

Comment: That means "you're on your own". Not the first time :)

Comment: I wonder if they thought about making i18n module specifications publicly available so that subject matter experts could comment on that...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use the "multilingual" word for search on Google...
I suppose that it will take months to complete (the roadmap was updated on March), so there is another method to handle internationalization?

Comment: 'i18n' can mean many different things, what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Best current equivalent (2018-12) is probably https://github.com/golang/go/milestones

Answer (score 6):

The new [template package](http://golang.org/pkg/template/) allows you to at add a function to template's function map, that would transform the given string to a localized version. What's going on underneath would be up to you for now, as the language choice could be based on headers sent by the browser.

That's a very basic use case for adding localized messages in a web app, for one.

Can't wait for the proper support for internationalization, local date and time formats.