# libraries for localization in go

Tags: go, internationalization

Do you have experience with localization (or i18n, l10n) with go? I thought, that I could read preferences sent by browser and provide response accoring to request. But I found only few attempts to something like this. Please sent me, if I'm wrong in some ideas.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message looks very complicated, documentation is disarranged and sometimes obsolete. It looks that is used only by very small group of people.

https://github.com/gosexy/gettext looks interesting, but if I understand well problem is in call SetLocale. That does not allow me to use two goroutines with different language at the same time if I don't want to synchronize goroutines very often.

https://godoc.org/github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n (or something based on this) looks that it should work. I'm going to play with this library, because it looks like the most usable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585362/how-to-handle-i18n-in-go

Comment: Related, read this blog post: [Language and Locale Matching in Go](http://blog.golang.org/matchlang)

Comment: I also find a gotcha with the last mentioned library i18n. Usually the library is executed from function template.Execute.That looks fine, but before using we have to call func (*Template) Funcs and this is a problem. Usually we parse template just one, but it is not safe to call Funcs from different goroutines without any sync mechanism.

Comment: The simplest would be sent language as template argument, but that is terrible - it forces some work in each template and each calling T. Yuck